# Where is my mistake? (BMI calculator)

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Arraygedoens {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bmi;
    String eingabe1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Geben Sie Ihr Gewicht ein(KG)", 
            "Gewicht", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String eingabe2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Geben Sie Ihre Höhe ein (Meter)", 
            "Höhe", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    int gewicht = Integer.parseint(eingabe1);
    int höhe = Integer.parse(eingabe2);
    bmi = gewicht/(höhe*2);
    if(bmi<20){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Bisch ein bissl Schlank he", 
                "BMI", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else if (bmi>20) {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Dein Gewicht ist passend", "BMI", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else if(bmi>40) {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Du bist zu FETT!)", "BMI", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

It always shows me a error message that tells me that it cannot find the symbols while parsing the strings, can somebody help me?

Comment: There's at least one typo: `Integer.parseint(eingabe1);` should have a capital `I` in `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks man! Worked.

Comment: You should reverse the `if (bmi > 20)` and `if (bmi > 40)` branches. The `bmi > 40` branch is logically unreachable: if `bmi > 40` then it will always be `> 20`.

Comment: You ask the user to enter the height in meters and then you try to parse the entered string as an integer? If I can only enter 1 or 2 for height, your BMI calcultation will not be accurate enogh to be useful. :-)

Comment: I notice you’re using the polite “Sie” when trying to persuade the user to give away sensitive information, but the intimate “du” and “dein” once the user has done that. :-)

Comment: It’s an aside, but your formula for the BMI is wrong. The height in meters should be squared. So it’s `gewicht / (höhe * höhe)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke diese Variante sollte es korrigieren :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BMI-Rechner { //Besser : BMI-Rechner oder ähnlich...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bmi;
    String eingabe1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Geben Sie Ihr Gewicht ein(KG)", 
            "Gewicht", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String eingabe2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Geben Sie Ihre Höhe ein (Meter)", 
            "Höhe", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    int gewicht = Integer.parseInt(eingabe1); //Tippfehler korrigiert
    int höhe = Integer.parseInt(eingabe2); //Tippfehler korrigiert
    bmi = gewicht/(höhe*2);
    if(bmi<20){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bisch ein bissl Schlank he", //Hier muss nichts eingegeben werden
                "BMI", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else if (bmi>20 && bmi<40) { //Der BMI muss auch kleiner als 40 sein 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Dein Gewicht ist passend", "BMI", //Hier muss auch nichts eingegeben werden
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else if(bmi>40) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Du bist zu FETT!)", "BMI", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //Hier muss ebenfals nichts eingegeben werden
    }

}
} //Geschweifte Klammer um Klasse zu beenden
```

bei mir hat es jedenfalls funktioniert...

Comment: Noch zwei Dinge: Sie können kein Strich in Klassenname haben. Vorschlag: `BmiRechner` statt `BMI-Rechner`. Eingabe: `80` und `2`. BMI: 20. Ausgabe: nichts! Also besser: `} else if (bmi < 40)`. Oder wenn Sie `} else if (bmi >= 20 && bmi < 40)` vorziehen. BMI == 40 dasselbe.

Comment: danke. ich bin noch ziemlich neu bei java...